# Exporting composition as image using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, print-composer, image

QGIS Print Composer has tool "Save As Image" and I found appropriate function in QGIS source code [exportCompositionAsImage](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/a50719b7e9dc23ba4abd24ce6ee859691d1832ee/src/app/composer/qgscomposer.cpp#L1615). Is it possible to get access to existing Print Composer from Python console and perform this operation - export composition as image with composer settings.

After help from @ndawson, I'm using `printPageAsRaster` function for printing different combinations of layers created with [layerCombinations](https://github.com/olivierdalang/layerCombinations) plugin:

```
from layerCombinations import classFactory
lc = classFactory(iface)
lc_manager = lc.manager
combinations = lc_manager.combinationsList
composition = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
composition_items = composition.items()
for cmb in combinations:
  for item in composition_items:
    if item.type() ==  65641: #this is the type of ComposerMap
      lc_manager.applyCombinationToMap(cmb, item)
  image = composition.printPageAsRaster(0)
  image.save('/home/dr/' + cmb +'.png','png')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of existing composer windows:

```
composers = iface.activeComposers()
```

Then, you need to get a reference to a specific composition:

```
c = composers[0].composition()
```

Render the page as an image (0 refers to the page number):

```
image = c.printPageAsRaster(0)
```

Save the image to disk (first argument is the filename, second is the format):

```
image.save('output.png','png')
```

So, the entire code should look something like this:

```
c = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
image = c.printPageAsRaster(0)
image.save('output.png','png')
```

Comment: Update #1: I've added code sample of using this functionality.