# Exporting current view as georeferenced image using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, image, png

I found [Exporting composition as image using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/103128/115) to export the current view as an image.

The following code works and was accepted as an answer.

> ```
> c = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
>
> image = c.printPageAsRaster(0)
>
> image.save('output.png', 'png')
> ```

Sadly, the images produced by this code are not georeferenced, even if I use different image formats.

How is it possible to programmatically export current view as georeferenced image with QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage( "myGeoreferencedView.png" )
```

It exports both PNG and PNGw files. The latter is known as [World file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)  and contains coordinate information.

Comment: But not the crs, though maybe there is a gdal aux created as well?

Comment: Nope, only two files are generated. You can choose among several formats like TIF or TIFF, but you'll only get the raster and its corresponding World file.

Comment: I requested GTiff some years ago, they may be ready for this now? It's a real lost opp