# Exporting Images using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, image

I am attempting to export an image based on a portion of the map.

I have written code that successfully identifies the area of the map I would like to output, but I am having trouble exporting anything other then a white screen.

I think it has something to do with the following two lines
I'm not sure I am actually moving the canvas to the correct portion of the map and I am not sure I am pointing the mapexport to the same layout I am filling up.

```
map.zoomToExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
mapexport = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)


import os

from qgis.core import (
    QgsGeometry,
    QgsMapSettings,
    QgsPrintLayout,
    QgsMapSettings,
    QgsMapRendererParallelJob,
    QgsLayoutItemLabel,
    QgsLayoutItemLegend,
    QgsLayoutItemMap,
    QgsLayoutItemPolygon,
    QgsLayoutItemScaleBar,
    QgsLayoutExporter,
    QgsLayoutItem,
    QgsLayoutPoint,
    QgsLayoutSize,
    QgsUnitTypes,
    QgsProject,
    QgsFillSymbol,
    QgsAbstractValidityCheck,
    check,
)

from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import (
    QPolygonF,
    QColor,
)

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import (
    QPointF,
    QRectF,
    QSize,
)


metersPerPixel = 16

image_location = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "render.png")


sizelayer = iface.activeLayer()
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers([sizelayer])
settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))

totalmapRect = sizelayer.extent()
xStart = totalmapRect.xMinimum()
xEnd = totalmapRect.xMaximum()

print(xStart)
print(xEnd)

yStart = totalmapRect.yMinimum()
yEnd = totalmapRect.yMaximum()

corner1 = QgsPointXY(xStart,yStart)
corner2 = QgsPointXY(xStart,yEnd)
corner3 = QgsPointXY(xEnd,yEnd)
corner4 = QgsPointXY(xEnd,yStart)

#Create a measure object
distance = QgsDistanceArea()

#distance.setEllipsoid(True)
#Set the ellipsoid over which QGIS will perform calculations, e.g., WGS84:

distance.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
#Now you can measure the distance once again (which will give you ~322.48m.):

#Measure the distance
height = distance.measureLine(corner1, corner2)
width = distance.measureLine(corner2, corner3)

print(width)
print(height)

#printed raster will have (width * metersPerPixel) meters in X and
#(height * metersPerPixel) meters in Y
xpixels = width / metersPerPixel
ypixels = height / metersPerPixel

print(xpixels)
print(ypixels)

settings.setOutputSize(QSize(xpixels, ypixels))
settings.setExtent(sizelayer.extent())

#Insert Layout Information

project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()


map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
# Set map item position and size (by default, it is a 0 width/0 height item placed at 0,0)
map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(0,0, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(width,height, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMeters))
# Provide an extent to render
map.zoomToExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())

base_path = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath())
pdf_path = os.path.join('C:/VBS Logs/', "output.pdf")

mapexport = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
mapexport.exportToPdf(pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
mapexport.exportToImage('C:/VBS Logs/test_render2.png', QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)

def finished():
    img = render.renderedImage()
    # save the image; e.g. img.save("/Users/myuser/render.png","png")
    #img.save(image_location, "png")
    img.save('C:/VBS Logs/test_render1.png', "png")

render.finished.connect(finished)

# Start the rendering
render.start()

# The following loop is not normally required, we
# are using it here because this is a standalone example.
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QEventLoop
loop = QEventLoop()
render.finished.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec_()
```

Comment: Are you trying to export a map or a layout to an image format?  In either case, have you tried searching the QGIS documentation and GIS SE using criteria that include those terms?  Hopefully, doing so would give you some ideas as to what needs to be in your code. Once you’ve made a code attempt, if you are still stuck and present it here, you will have a question suitable for this site.

Comment: I am trying to export a map, with whatever layers are currently shown in the main window.

I tried to search the documentation and the forums, but don't see anything that corresponds.

I found the following, but that seems to apply to layouts in the print composer not just straight map exports.
https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutExporter.html#details

The exact functionality I am looking for lies entirely within the manual operation Project menu -> Save Image As, I just can't seem to find documentation that matches that functionality.
Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Perhaps review https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/194546/115.  If you can get code running that exports your map as an image  then I think your next step will be to try and specify the map extent within which you want that to happen.  Gaining control over resolution could come later.