# Apply .qml style to a folder of tif images

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to apply a .qml style from QGIS to each individual .tif image, contained within a folder, using python, but I can't get it to work. Is there a way to do this without loading the images into QGIS?

Here is my code which isn't working:

```
import glob     
for layers in glob.glob('E:/Clipped/*.tif'):        
    layers.loadNamedStyle('E:/style.qml')
```

Comment: What is the point of styling layers without loading them?

Comment: I am wanting the final rendered .tif files so I can load them into a report. If there is away to load the images into QGIS and apply the style then save them out as rendered images all via a python scrit then this would work too but I'm struggling to load all .tifs at once with a script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load each raster into the canvas, apply the qml file and then export back to a pdf/jpg/tiff etc. Create a template using print composer and then take a look at this [blog post](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/) and this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103128/how-to-programmatically-export-a-composition-as-image) for some idea on how to code the export.