# Seeking Multiprint plugin for QGIS 3?

Tags: print-composer, software-recommendations, qgis-3

I'm working on QGIS3 and I'm looking for a plugin to print multicomposers at once. I know that in QGIS2 there is a plugin (multiprint) that does this, but for QGIS3, I can not find anything similar.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a ready-made solution for this in QGIS 3 *yet*. The plugin `Instant Print` may be somewhat helpful, depending on your needs. Or you can use the python console, as in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103128/how-to-programmatically-export-a-composition-as-image

Comment: Actually a I'm using instant print, but is not so good for what I need. Python is good option, but i just have some basic basic notions. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to go the Python route, make your best effort at coding it yourself, then post a new question and include the code you have so far. People are pretty willing to help as long as you're not asking them to write code from scratch for you.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But I just know the basics of python: variables, print and arithmetic, nothing else. I'm studying by my self  a bit more of python, but isn't still enough to make pieces of code and understand how it works. Maybe In a few months I will be able to do this and ask you again. Thank you guys and sorry.

Comment: What exactly is this plugin supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maps Printer in QGIS3 to export several layouts.